# Get .current value in useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a start/stop timer function that will start or stop the timer. It works perfectly but I'm trying to have it stop at 30 seconds and run `saveTrial()`. I've tried console logging `timer.current` and `time` at various locations, but neither are representing what the current timer is showing in seconds.

```
const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
let timer = useRef(0);

const startStopTimer = () => {
   if (!timer.current)
     timer.current = setInterval(() => {
         setTime(time => time + 1);
      }, 1000);
   } else {
     clearInterval(timer.current);
     timer.current = 0;
   }
};
```

Comment: I think your `startStopTimer` function needs to be inside of a `useEffect` hook.

Comment: `timer.current` isn't what the timer is in seconds - it's the internal reference to the interval [timeoutID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) that you store in a ref so that you can clear the interval later.

Answer (score 0):

Including `time` in useEffect as a dependency works perfectly.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (time === 10) {
        saveTrial();
    };
}, [time]);
```

Comment: Yes, but there will be a bug in your code I guess. You need to setTime(0) when you clear the interval otherwise the timer will be accumulated for the next interval restart.

Comment: I do have a `resetTimer` function that is called on another button click. `startStopTimer` is only meant to accumulate.